# Build Single pole changeover switch from 4066 Single pole, single throw

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches

I am trying to build this circuit which requires two SPCO switch that go between two voltage values but I only have access to 4066N SPST switches.

[image: Circuit]

I am not sure if there are better alternative designs but the one I came up with was to use two different switches and an inverter for the clock. Apologies for the terrible MS paint drawing.

[image: Possible Solution]
Edit: That triangle thing on the second IN is a ground, not another opamp.

My question is will this work? I'm wondering if tying the outputs together like that would cause problems but I don't understand the circuit well enough to know for sure.

Also, this is more of a notation question but the first opamp only shows an input into the + terminal. Is the other one grounded by convention or is it trying to say something else?

Comment: Tying the output of the two 4066's together is not a problem, since only one can be active at a time.  I assume the line labeled IN at the bottom is the feedback line connected to the voltage divider.  I don't know why you show it connected to another op-amp.   The op-amp with the single input is labelled as an AC amplifier having a gain of 60 dB.  It is only depicted as a black box and the circuitry around the op-amp to accomplish this is not shown.

Comment: @tcrosley So the finite turn on time of the analog switch won't cause any problems with having the outputs tied together? I had a gut feeling that it might but I wasn't sure how to check that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work but with a small modification. The output from the AC amplifier is decoupled via the output capacitor and therefore the voltage reaching the 4066 switch might have a strange dc value on it. The possible solution is to not ac couple but rely on the dc connection to the ac amplifier - there shouldn't be any problem designing the ac amp to have a "centred" dc rail coming from the device so that the 4066 switch is seeing an ac voltage mid-rail of its supplies.

On the most left-hand switch you ought to have a pull-down resistor after the switch and before it feeds to the AC amplifier, probably in the order of 1M ohm.

Any time you use analogue switches in this type of application you have to watch out for the switches inherent leakage currents charging up capacitors and this is always alleviated by dc coupling.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by decoupled? I've probably run across the concept in my coursework previously but I'm not explicitly familiar with the term.

Comment: In my 1st line I'm meaning the dc is prevented from exiting the AC amplifier i.e. it's not-coupled thru. Some folk would call it dc blocking. Not sure there is a convention on this. Sorry it might be misleading dude.